# How to use jumpToPage Inside page without PageView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a first page with PageView.

```
PageController _pageController = PageController();
List<Widget> _screens = [HomeScreen(), PanicScreen(), ChartScreen()]; 

PageView(
controller: _pageController,
children: _screens
)
```

I have a button inside the **HomeScreen()** and I want to jump in **ChartScreen()**

**HomeScreen.dart**

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                     onTap: () {
                       _pageController.jumpToPage(1);
                  },
```

```
ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 176 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty'
```

Answer (score 0):

In HomeScreen you just created a new scroll controller. but you did not set it to the PageView's controller property. So, it's throwing an error like this. you have to use the same controller variable which you already assigned to the PageView controller property to perform `jumpToPage` method. Can you try the below codes?

```
PageController _pageController = PageController();
List<Widget> _screens = [HomeScreen(controller: _pageController), PanicScreen(controller: _pageController), ChartScreen(controller: _pageController)]; 

PageView(
controller: _pageController,
children: _screens
)
```

Use the scroll controller to achieve the `jumpToPage` method.

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
 const _HomeScreenState({this.controller}); 
 
final PageController controller;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                     onTap: () {
                       controller.jumpToPage(1);
                  },
}
```

Or Use the controller as a Global variable and use it to the HomeScreen page. Make sure if the controller is attached to the PageView's controller property before using it.